# Postgres: querying jsonb array with an array

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, json, rails

My products table has a jsonb column called 'specs'.

This specs hash will often have an array field, let's call it 'spec_options'.

When querying this table, I need to find any product that has certain spec options.

Let's say we have a product with these spec_options:

```
['b', 'c', 'd']
```

And the user wants to find products with these spec_options:

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

The query I need should return find above product.

This where clause worked just fine when the field wasn't an array:

`'["a", "b", "c"]'::jsonb ? (specs->>'spec_options')`

But now that it's an array, I think I need to use the `|?` operator, and I can't work out how to get the right side of this operation into the correct format. (I think it needs to be text[] but I'm not sure.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the @> operator.

From the [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html):

> @>    Does the left JSON value contain within it the right value?

So in your case it would look something like this:

```
select * from products where specs @> '{"spec_options": ["a", "b", "c"]}';
```